# MySQL fetch query PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There are only 30 values in the table but `mysqli_num_rows($result) return 60`
Same query is being executed twice , here is the code :

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','***','***','***');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    # code...
    echo "Could not connect to MYSQL database".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "select * from ticket_staff";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo   $row["t_ID"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


?>
```

[here is the screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wuN6.png)

Comment: Did you check the all records of table `ticket_staff` manually using any database software?

Comment: yes , but no records are repeating in the table

Comment: Try to use `mysqli_close($con);` just after getting the `$result` and `mysqli_free_result($result);` just after while loop.